# How to fix type inference issue with FutureBuilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, type-inference, flutter-futurebuilder

While working on a Flutter project, I encountered a type inference issue related to the `FutureBuilder` widget. I am trying to fetch a list of products asynchronously and display them using `FutureBuilder`. However, I'm facing two main problems:

1. **Type Inference Issue**: The compiler is unable to infer the type parameter 'T' for the `FutureBuilder`. It suggests that there is a mismatch between the expected type by the `builder` parameter and the actual type being passed.

   - Error Message: `Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. Tried to infer 'List<ProductModel>?' for 'T' which doesn't work. Parameter 'builder' declared as 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<T>)' but argument is 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductModel>?>)'.`
2. **Argument Type Issue**: There seems to be a discrepancy in the file paths for the `ProductModel` definition used in the argument type and the parameter type, causing a type mismatch error.

   - Error Message: `The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductModel>?>)' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<ProductModel>?>)'.`

I have researched this issue on Stack Overflow and found similar questions, but none that address this specific scenario where the type inference fails in the context of using `FutureBuilder` with a custom model class. I've attempted to specify explicit types and ensure my models are correctly defined, but the issue persists.

#### Code Snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mongodb_server/api_service.dart';
import 'models/product_model.dart';

class ProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductListState createState() => _ProductListState();
}

class _ProductListState extends State<ProductList> {
  // Code simplified for brevity. Includes essential parts to reproduce the issue.

  Widget loadProducts() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<ProductModel>?>(
      future: APIService.getProducts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return productList(snapshot.data);
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}

Widget productList(List<ProductModel>? products) {
  // Widget implementation that uses the products list
}
```

Could someone help me understand why the type inference is failing and how to resolve the argument type mismatch issue?

Comment: For problem 1: Can you be more specific about the error you're observing and what line is triggering it? For problem 2: Somehow you're trying to consume `mongodb_server\lib\models\product_model.dart` with inconsistent capitalization (i.e., both as `mongodb_server` and as `MongoDB_server`).  The Dart compiler will treat these as two independent paths even if you're using a case-insensitive file-system.  Figure out where that inconsistency is coming from and fix it.

Comment: Hello, I updated problem 1, it triggers the problem at lines 98-110

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thank you so much, your advice about problem 2 also fixed problem 1